# Using Facebook's Graph API to access individual elements from grouped timeline posts

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to use Facebook's JavaScript SDK and Graph API to access individual posts from a grouped cluster. Facebook automatically grouped all the birthday wishes on my timeline. When I post a query to "/me/feed", I get a single object with 'story' : '.....posted on your timeline'. I can't get the ids for the individual posts. I'm trying to comment on those posts, but all I have is this single id of the grouped posts. Is there a workaround?

My current API call looks like this

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        response.data.forEach((post)=> {
            //Do what needs to be done
        }   
      });
```

Comment: You can not get individual post ids from such a story. But you should see the individual posts showing up in `/me/feed` anyway, no?

Comment: Nope. Individual posts other than the ones from the  grouped story are visible.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure it out? Can't find anything on the doc